# How do I connect to my Huawei EG 1732USB modem from terminal?

Tags: command-line, internet, usb-modem

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 & i'd like to know how can i connect my USB modem through terminal . I mean creating connection and calling it,  I want to do from terminal .

Thank you .

Comment: Take a look at [How to Connect Internet](http://www.techtipsgeek.com/how-to-connect-internet-with-wireless-usb-modem-in-linux/13327/)

Comment: @Mitch Thank you for the link but its old & not suitable for present modems .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell us what modem it is (brand, model). Anyway Mitch was right on the link, although today, things are a bit easier.

For telling model of modem, on a console:

```
sudo lsusb
```

#### Method 1

1. Take a look at the output of `lsusb`. You should see your modem assigned to ttyUSB* ports:

   ```
   sudo ls /dev/ttyUSB*
   ```

   ttyUSB0 - Should be the modem
   ttyUSB1 - Should be the USB module
2. Download a dialer

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wvdial ppp
   ```
3. Configure your connection

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
   ```

   and use something like the following:

   ```
   [Dialer hsdpa]
   Phone = *99***1#
   Username = vodafone
   Password = vodafone
   Stupid Mode = 1
   Dial Command = ATDT
   Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
   Baud = 460800
   Init2 = ATZ
   Init3 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
   ISDN = 0
   Modem Type = Analog Modem
   ```

   You need to set your Phone number, username and password, these are values given by your operator.

   Also set the connection on Modem (`/dev/ttyUSB0`)

   The name hsdpa, is generic, you can use whatever name you want.

When dialing your connection, is this name you use.

If using PIN code add this before Init2

```
    Init1 = AT+CPIN=9999
```

where 9999 is changed for your PIN-code

1. Start your connection

   ```
   sudo wvdial hsdpa
   ```

hsdpa is the example name i've used, you have to use the one you choosed in wvdial.conf

[Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Huawei_E220)

Comment: its huawei modem , EG 1732

Comment: Then the method should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes i have tried but its not worked for me . changes are there

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Errors? Outputs?

Comment: You talking about mitch link or youR answer ?

Comment: My answer. Saying only that doesn't work doesn't help us. You have to give us error messages and more detailed information.

Comment: wait.. i thought you're talking about the link . i will be back in few min with report.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/juTKw7wk according my ISP all are fields are empty , but how to give apn here ? look at the link

Comment: You entered: `sudo wvdial hspda` you should enter `sudo wvdial hsdpa`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/H3cWiWds but as per my ISP those are empty .:( http://www.vodafone.in/internet/pages/vodafonemobileconnect_mum.aspx?cid=mum

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the values i think are the ones for Vodafone. Please update your wvdial.conf

Comment: http://pastebin.com/z5w2MMtU   its waiting there , nothing up .but some progress. :D

Comment: Try Phone = *99***16# like it was before...

Comment: Now its saying the device is busy . many times i have tried even i have re connected the device but nothing up .http://pastebin.com/aujDwCPv

Comment: Try reboot your pc, and try again, if not try to get the parameter PHONE from your network provider. I think that's what's missing

Answer (score 1):

you could use [sakis3g](http://wiki.sakis3g.org/wiki/index.php?title=Sakis3G_UI#Text_mode) text mode..